# UK visa refused due to lack of ties... how to reapply?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image]

I applied for a Visit visa and which in my my savings bank account i had Gh2700 cedis equivalent to 509.34 pounds which i also presented evidence of source of fund monies i receive from family and friends. My question is was my bank account savings money insufficient that made the ECO refuse my visit visa application describing my personal financial and economic circumstance.Hope to hear from you guys here

Comment: You have yet another great answer from the community, but looking at your history, you have never actually accepted an answer. Have you been dissatisfied?  Are we doing it wrong?  Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 and http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and acknowledge the answer below or any others that the community offers. Thanks!

Comment: Did your family and friends give you the money to put in the bank with the intention to apply for a visa? Was it shortly before the visa application? If yes, this could be a red flag too.

Comment: @pnuts,this was an application i made in November for Christmas holidays but was refused cause i had Gh2,700 cedis and January i got invitation letter from the British army so am doing new application to submit next week and able to build my account to Gh9,000 from monies i received from friends and families/

Comment: @Quora Feans,nope was my own savings in my account which i didnt do fund parking, but the amount in it was Gh2700 equivalent to 509.34 pounds on my personal financial circumstance which got me refused

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This letter is less clear than what I'm used to reading, but what I can read from this is:

> "*I am not satified that the documents submitted demonstrate that you have strong economic or financial circumstances in Ghana*"

Meaning: yes, in all likelihood your bank statements showed that you're not financially fit to travel to the UK without engaging in illegal employment. The good news is, at least you didn't resort to funds parking (putting a large amount of money on your account to make it look good), which would not only have led to a visa refusal, but also damaged your credibility as an applicant.

GBP 509 on a savings account really isn't a whole lot, and unlike many countries, the UK won't accept without further ado "oh, my family is supporting me while I'm there" - in fact it could make them **even more** suspicious, as this proves you have ties to the UK that could prompt you to remain there illegally. This is not to say, of course, that you should have left out the details of your family in the UK.

So, in essence, now is not the time for you to visit the UK. Finish your studies, get a stable job, and give it another shot, preferably with the aid of a qualified solicitor. Even though the letters always say that new applications are entirely considered on their own merits, in practice having a refusal *is* a cause for increased caution upon a subsequent application, especially for people from "high-risk" countries.

Comment: I cannot see the image (firewall), but the part you quote sounds to me more like "you have neither job nor assets in Ghana, so you have no (economical) reason to return there once you are in the UK". What you explain would be explained as "you lack the means to substain yourself while in the UK".

Comment: @SJuan76 as far as I can see and understand, you both are right. Second bullet is about lack of funds, and third about lack of reasons to leave UK.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you are not working in Ghana, but financially dependent on your family (in Ghana and/or in the UK)

When you are financially dependent on your family, you need to convince the embassy about two things in your application:

- It is in your best interest to return to your home country after the trip.
- It is in your sponsor's best interest that you return.

Can you convince them that returning to Ghana and studying is better for you than working illegally in the UK? It probably depends on the kind of financial support you receive in Ghana and the quality of your school/ college/ university.

Is it better for your family to continue paying money for your studies in Ghana than to have you stay illegally in the UK? It depends on the financial and social situation of your family. Maybe they would push you to stay in the UK and study there in a high-reputation school (I don't know if schools there check your immigration status)? Maybe they want you to work illegally and support yourself (in the UK), so they do not have to continue supporting you.

It is not enough that you act in good faith and have every intentions to leave the UK. You must convince the embassy that it is in your and your family's best interest to do so (Think of it from a game-theoretical point of view).

Answer (score 4):

This visa application refusal must be quite upsetting to you, and you are right to perceive it in the light of your human right to visit your family.

However, nation-states, representing their people, also have rights and responsibilities, and your personal circumstances do appear to show that you are presently not in a good position to travel for the purpose of visiting you family.

I live in Europe, and I wouldn't risk going to a nearby country if I had about 500 GBP and was a student, regardless of any third-party support. Some small unexpected details during travel can cause you to spend significantly more money than planned. It comes down to common sense, and the UK visa officers are encouraged to practice it.

Don't take it personally. I would suggest doing what you can to improve your personal circumstances.

Comment: sure have worked on my personal circumstance which this time around being able to acquire land and property documents and able to save to Gh9000 equivalent to 1697.79 pounds to apply for another visa to the Uk to attend British Army assessment  with my sponsor sponsoring me and my dad also

Comment: Ethan, from reading your history and plans, you're very likely to be refused. I am originally from Ghana myself and have had many interactions with UK immigration and consular through visits and applications. You're seriously risking another refusal and appear fixated on going to the UK. Take Gayot Fows answer seriously.